# Finding the number of alphabetical strings which may be constructed from a set.

Tags: combinatorics

How would one find the number of alphabetical, 3-letter strings which may be constructed from the set $\{A, B, C,\dots,J\}$ if each letter may only be used once?

I am aware $10!\div7!$ strings may be constructed if one doesn't follow the alphabetical stipulation, but I can't figure out how to mathematically eliminate the others.

Comment: What does "alphabetical" mean?

Comment: If all you mean is that the letters have to be in alphabetical order (so $ABJ$ is good but $BAJ$ is not) then the answer is $\binom {10}3$ as any set of three distinct letters can be arranged in order in a unique way.

Comment: Wouldnt that just be $10 \choose 3$?

Answer (score 1):

If by "alphabetical" you mean the string must be in alphabetical order rather than the usual meaning that the strings are composed of letters, then the answer is simply ${10 \choose 3} =\frac {10!}{3!7!} $.

Since you are putting them in alphabetical order it doesn't matter which order you pick them from.  As for any set of $3$ letters there are $3!$ ways to arrange them, then $\frac {10!}{7!} $ counts *EVERY* way to pick $3$ lettets, it picks every triplet $3! $ times for every possible order.  So we need to divide by $3!$.

We call ${n\choose m}=\frac {n!}{(n-m)!m!} $, "$n $ choose $m $" (or sometimes "choose $m$ from $n$) because it is the number of ways to choose a set of $m $ objects from a set of $n $ objects.

====

Maybe a better explanation.

$P=$ number of ways to select 3 in distinct orders $=10*9*8=\frac {10!}{3} $.

$C=$ number of ways to choose groups of 3 wher order doesn't matter $=??? $

$k=$ number of different ways to order a group of 3 $=3! $.

Clearly $P =$ number of ways to select 3 in order = number of groups of 3 times number of ways to order a group $=C*k$.

So $\frac {10!}{7!}=C*3! $.

So $C =\frac {10!}{7!3!}={10\choose 3} $.

Answer (score 1):

Consider filling the three "slots" or letter positions of words.

The first position can be filled with any one of the first eight letters.  (You cannot fill it in with the ninth or tenth letter and still get an alphabetical word by filling in the remaining letters.)  The second position can be filled with any letter one greater than the first letter and up to the ninth letter.  (It cannot be the 10th letter, otherwise you cannot fill in the last letter and get an alphabetical word.)  The third position can be any letter one greater than the second letter up to the 10th letter:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^8 \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^9 \sum\limits_{k=j+1}^{10} 1 = 120$.

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{c}\} & \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{d}\} & \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{e}\} & \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{f}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{g}\} & \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{h}\} \\
 \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{b},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{d}\} & \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{e}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{f}\} & \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{g}\} \\
 \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{h}\} & \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{c},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{e}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{f}\} & \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{g}\} \\
 \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{h}\} & \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{d},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{e},\text{f}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{e},\text{g}\} & \{\text{a},\text{e},\text{h}\} \\
 \{\text{a},\text{e},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{e},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{f},\text{g}\} & \{\text{a},\text{f},\text{h}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{f},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{f},\text{j}\} \\
 \{\text{a},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{a},\text{g},\text{i}\} & \{\text{a},\text{g},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{h},\text{i}\} &
   \{\text{a},\text{h},\text{j}\} & \{\text{a},\text{i},\text{j}\} \\
 \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{d}\} & \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{e}\} & \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{f}\} & \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{g}\} &
   \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{h}\} & \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{b},\text{c},\text{j}\} & \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{e}\} & \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{f}\} & \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{g}\} &
   \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{h}\} & \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{b},\text{d},\text{j}\} & \{\text{b},\text{e},\text{f}\} & \{\text{b},\text{e},\text{g}\} & \{\text{b},\text{e},\text{h}\} &
   \{\text{b},\text{e},\text{i}\} & \{\text{b},\text{e},\text{j}\} \\
 \{\text{b},\text{f},\text{g}\} & \{\text{b},\text{f},\text{h}\} & \{\text{b},\text{f},\text{i}\} & \{\text{b},\text{f},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{b},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{b},\text{g},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{b},\text{g},\text{j}\} & \{\text{b},\text{h},\text{i}\} & \{\text{b},\text{h},\text{j}\} & \{\text{b},\text{i},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{e}\} & \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{f}\} \\
 \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{g}\} & \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{h}\} & \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{i}\} & \{\text{c},\text{d},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{c},\text{e},\text{f}\} & \{\text{c},\text{e},\text{g}\} \\
 \{\text{c},\text{e},\text{h}\} & \{\text{c},\text{e},\text{i}\} & \{\text{c},\text{e},\text{j}\} & \{\text{c},\text{f},\text{g}\} &
   \{\text{c},\text{f},\text{h}\} & \{\text{c},\text{f},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{c},\text{f},\text{j}\} & \{\text{c},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{c},\text{g},\text{i}\} & \{\text{c},\text{g},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{c},\text{h},\text{i}\} & \{\text{c},\text{h},\text{j}\} \\
 \{\text{c},\text{i},\text{j}\} & \{\text{d},\text{e},\text{f}\} & \{\text{d},\text{e},\text{g}\} & \{\text{d},\text{e},\text{h}\} &
   \{\text{d},\text{e},\text{i}\} & \{\text{d},\text{e},\text{j}\} \\
 \{\text{d},\text{f},\text{g}\} & \{\text{d},\text{f},\text{h}\} & \{\text{d},\text{f},\text{i}\} & \{\text{d},\text{f},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{d},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{d},\text{g},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{d},\text{g},\text{j}\} & \{\text{d},\text{h},\text{i}\} & \{\text{d},\text{h},\text{j}\} & \{\text{d},\text{i},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{e},\text{f},\text{g}\} & \{\text{e},\text{f},\text{h}\} \\
 \{\text{e},\text{f},\text{i}\} & \{\text{e},\text{f},\text{j}\} & \{\text{e},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{e},\text{g},\text{i}\} &
   \{\text{e},\text{g},\text{j}\} & \{\text{e},\text{h},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{e},\text{h},\text{j}\} & \{\text{e},\text{i},\text{j}\} & \{\text{f},\text{g},\text{h}\} & \{\text{f},\text{g},\text{i}\} &
   \{\text{f},\text{g},\text{j}\} & \{\text{f},\text{h},\text{i}\} \\
 \{\text{f},\text{h},\text{j}\} & \{\text{f},\text{i},\text{j}\} & \{\text{g},\text{h},\text{i}\} & \{\text{g},\text{h},\text{j}\} &
   \{\text{g},\text{i},\text{j}\} & \{\text{h},\text{i},\text{j}\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

Alternatively, there are ${10 \choose 3}$ ways to choose three separate letters, keeping their arbitrary order.  For each selection of three given letters, only one of the $3!$ arbitrarily-ordered sets is in *alphabetical* order.  Hence:

${{10 \choose 3} \over 3!} = 120$.

More generally, if you have $n$ ordered elements from which you create ordered subsets containing $k$ elements, you have:

${{n \choose k} \over k!} = {n! \over (n-k)!(k!)^2}$ "alphabetical" subsets.